# Data not adding in firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hello there here is my code but its not adding data to firebase. I had created a collection and every in firebase I had also done printing everything works fine but the only problem is data is not adding in the firestore whenever I press send

```
    import 'dart:ffi';
import 'package:chat_app/constants.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id='chatscreen';
  const ChatScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChatScreen> createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  FirebaseFirestore _firestore=FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String? textMessage;
  final _auth=FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late User loggedInUser;
  @override
  void initState() {
    getCurrentUser();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getCurrentUser()async
  {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
      }
    }
    catch(e){

    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Ranchat',style: title.copyWith(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 30),),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed:(){
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, Welcome_Screen.id);
              } ,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout_outlined),),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (value){
                      textMessage=value;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                      hintText: 'Type a message',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,width: 2),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,width: 2),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Material(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    child: Icon(Icons.send,color: Colors.green,),
                    onPressed: ()async{
                     await _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                        'text':textMessage,
                        'sender':loggedInUser,
                      });
                     print('done');
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Whenever I click on send here is the error i tried to search for it on google and other platforms but didnt fin any solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It works by replacing:

`loggedInUser` with `loggedInUser!.email`

and

`late User` with `User?`.